# cant access httpd deployment after exposing via service on browser on k8s playground

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, service, minikube

using [labs.play-with-k8s.com](https://labs.play-with-k8s.com/). I created a small k8s cluster: 2 worker nodes, 1 master.

deployment of 4 pods with httpd image running and exposed thru service.
I asked chatgpt how to hit the pods from outside - browser. It suggested port-foward cmd or 'kubectl proxy'. HOwever to no results.

node2 is master node and 2 pods run on each worker node.

deployment has containerPort as 77 and service has targetport 77, they do match. i choose it to be not-default 80 so i can check that using another port works and service properly exposes deployment thru non-standard port.

deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: d
  name: d
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: d
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: d
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: httpd
        name: httpd
        ports:
        - containerPort: 77
```

service is of type node port, exposes on nodeport 31399.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: d-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: d
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 77
      nodePort: 31399
  type: NodePort
```

then i tried to hit with curl from outside into 1 **worker** node:
192.168.0.23 is ip of a worker node, 31399 is  nodeport where service supposed to expose the deployment

```
curl 192.168.0.23:31399
```

it gives: failed to connect, connection refused

I tried proxy forward and it did not work.

does service only work with standard 80 ports?

[image: kk]

Comment: Hi \`ERJAN\` have you tried hitting the port from other nodes and also since this is a playground provided you might not be having the public IP which is required if you are trying to accessing the url from your local machine.

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni, that's what i was thinking! it appears they closed it for public. i did could hit from inside from any worker node's ip using curl. it worked fine

Comment: Hi `ERJAN` for better visibility of the community I'm posting my comment as an answer, please let me if it's useful to you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment provided by me, the sole reason for this issue is that the IP addresses provided by the playground are private IP addresses and those can’t be accessed outside the cluster of the playground. So, if you want to access your sample application via a browser, try to create VMs in any cloud provider or in your local device and replicate the cluster so that you can access the application via browser.

Comment: thx u so much, i actually wanted to do this on aws. should i use managed EKS or just fire up ec2 myself?

Comment: @ERJAN It depends on how you like to implement it, if you use EKS, GKE or AKS you will get pre installed kubernetes cluster along with all the configurations you no need to use any join commands for adding the worker nodes and these can scale automatically without any human intervention if you have enabled auto scale option, whereas if you want to use ec2 you need to first select the OS and install kubernetes on top of it and do all the networking part to create the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

By defining `containerPort: 77` on your deployment template, you are only changing the exposed container port, but your httpd server will still listen on port 80 (as it is configured by default).

You need to change the `httpd listen` configuration to match your new exposed port.

If you wish to adapt the httpd default configuration, you need to update your **httpd.conf** with the `Listen 77` config.

For instance, if your prefer an "one-line workaround" still using the original httpd image, you can change the command/args to replace the listen config on every start:

```
  containers:
  - image: httpd
    name: httpd
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    args: ["sed -i 's/Listen 80/Listen 77/g' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf && exec /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -DFOREGROUND"]
    ports:
    - containerPort: 77
```

then you can curl with the IP of your k8snode:

```
$ curl http://<node-ip>:31399
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

- The `kubectl proxy` command starts a proxy server on your local machine and allows you to access the Kubernetes API server and services through this proxy.
- The `kubectl port-forward service/d-service 8080:80` will forward local port 8080 to port 80 on the d-service within the cluster. and you will be able to access the service by navigating to http://localhost:8080 in your terminal not in browser.

Comment: thx u, actually i did manage to hit the service on any worker node, but it happens inside the cluster; they probably closed the whole cluster , no public ip